# Going back to php form and auto submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am new to PHP, so sorry if the question sounds stupid, but I'm a little bit confused.

I have two .php pages

The first is browse.php where I have an HTML form (POST method).

When I submit the form I go to entries.php (the second page) where the data appear after interacting with mysql. (imagine that I get a table of entries)

In some cell of the tables, I want to create a link, that goes back to browse.php (with the cell data) and auto submit again the form, and then return to entries.php

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save Data in $_SESSION var

then forward via header to browser.php

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

check $_SESSION for you parameters when they are in fill html values and submit via javaskript

use jquery like

```
$('#form').submit(function(){return true;});
```

where #form is the id of your form